# How to support both 'regular' and 'readable' urls in Web API attribute rouring?

Tags: c#, url, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing, routeattribute

I have ASP.NET Web API 2.1 project with attribute routing enabled, and a controller action decorated as following:

```
[Route("api/product/barcode/{barcodeType}/{barcode}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetProduct([FromUri] BarcodeSearchCriteria searchCriteria)
```

where BarcodeSearchCriteria is a complex type:

```
public class BarcodeSearchCriteria
{
    public string Barcode { get; set; }

    public string BarcodeType { get; set; }
}
```

It works well for a 'regular' url like this:

```
/api/product/barcode/EAN/0747599330971
```

but how in the same time support an url like this:

```
/api/product/barcode/?barcodeType=EAN&barcode=0747599330971
```

I used to use it in my *.webtest before switched to 'readable` mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could have 2 routes in this case:

```
[Route("api/product/barcode")] //expects values from query string
[Route("api/product/barcode/{barcodeType}/{barcode}")] //expects value from route
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetProduct([FromUri] BarcodeSearchCriteria searchCriteria)
```

Comment: It seems it's used to work but stopped working some time ago. Now I'm getting the same error instead: "No action was found on the controller 'Product' that matches the request". When either 1 (default) or 2 (also with action) routes configured.

Comment: Hmm..this should work...make sure you have attribute routes registered `before` conventional routes in your configuration. This is because any requests which match conventional routes can never reach attributed controller/actions.

Comment: My mistake was in routes registration order. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no route defined for the regular Url with query string parameters.

Try making the route parameters optional like this.

```
[Route("api/product/barcode/{barcodeType=""}/{barcode=""}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetProduct([FromUri] BarcodeSearchCriteria searchCriteria)
```

So it should also match the route template `api/product/barcode` route.

Haven't tested, though hope you got my point.

Comment: I'm still getting an error: "No action was found on the controller 'Product' that matches the request." even having `ute(@"api/product/barcode/{barcodeType=""""}/{barcode=""""}")]`

Comment: Also google gives no advise how to specify a default for string parameter properly

Comment: You are right, Is it possible to decorate double route attribute against same action, i.e adding [Route("api/product/barcode")] also to the same method after removing optional decoration in second attribute.

Comment: Also for the sake of testing, can you specify any optional string than empty string ({barcodeType="a"}/{barcode="b"}) against the parameters and check if it works.

Comment: This is ridicules and weird but defaults don't work for me either way.